# jQuery - Header animation on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<header class="nb-header row-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="nb-logo row-fluid">
          <a href="#">
          logo
          </a>
       </div>
       <div class="nb-hamburger">
          Hamburger
       </div>
    </div>
   </header>
   <!--nb-header-->
   <div class="nb-menu-bar row-fluid">
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <ul>
  <li> <a href="#"> <span class="nb-menu-link"> Work </span> <span class="nb-menu-sub">
     What we’ve done </span> </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#"> <span class="nb-menu-link"> Services </span> <span class="nb-menu-sub">
     What we do </span> </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#"> <span class="nb-menu-link"> Studio </span> <span class="nb-menu-sub">
     Who we are </span> </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#"> <span class="nb-menu-link"> Contact </span> <span class="nb-menu-sub">
     Get in touch </span> </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#"> <span class="nb-menu-link"> Careers </span> <span class="nb-menu-sub">
     Join the team </span> </a> 
  </li>
      </ul>
                </div>
             </div>
Showing/hiding any HTML DOM element is a common scenario based on various business requirements. Since the time
of SPA (single page application) is evolved, you will find that on scroll position of browser, new elements are
shown and previous elements are hidden. There are tons of jQuery plugins available which can show/hide any HTML
element based on the scroll position but itâ€™s not advisable to use jQuery plugins for things which you can do
with simple jQuery code. So in this post, letâ€™s see how to show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll
position in the browser window using jQuery.Showing/hiding any HTML DOM element is a common scenario based on
various business requirements. Since the time of SPA (single page application) is evolved, you will find that
on scroll position of browser, new elements are shown and previous elements are hidden. There are tons of
jQuery plugins available which can show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll position but itâ€™s not
advisable to use jQuery plugins for things which you can do with simple jQuery code. So in this post, letâ€™s
see how to show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll position in the browser window using
jQuery.Showing/hiding any HTML DOM element is a common scenario based on various business requirements. Since
the time of SPA (single page application) is evolved, you will find that on scroll position of browser, new
elements are shown and previous elements are hidden. There are tons of jQuery plugins available which can
show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll position but itâ€™s not advisable to use jQuery plugins for
things which you can do with simple jQuery code. So in this post, letâ€™s see how to show/hide any HTML element
based on the scroll position in the browser window using jQuery.Showing/hiding any HTML DOM element is a common
scenario based on various business requirements. Since the time of SPA (single page application) is evolved,
you will find that on scroll position of browser, new elements are shown and previous elements are hidden.
There are tons of jQuery plugins available which can show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll position
but itâ€™s not advisable to use jQuery plugins for things which you can do with simple jQuery code. So in this
post, letâ€™s see how to show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll position in the browser window using
jQuery.Showing/hiding any HTML DOM element is a common scenario based on various business requirements. Since
the time of SPA (single page application) is evolved, you will find that on scroll position of browser, new
elements are shown and previous elements are hidden. There are tons of jQuery plugins available which can
show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll position but itâ€™s not advisable to use jQuery plugins for
things which you can do with simple jQuery code. So in this post, letâ€™s see how to show/hide any HTML element
based on the scroll position in the browser window using jQuery.Showing/hiding any HTML DOM element is a common
scenario based on various business requirements. Since the time of SPA (single page application) is evolved,
you will find that on scroll position of browser, new elements are shown and previous elements are hidden.
There are tons of jQuery plugins available which can show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll position
but itâ€™s not advisable to use jQuery plugins for things which you can do with simple jQuery code. So in this
post, letâ€™s see how to show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll position in the browser window using
jQuery.Showing/hiding any HTML DOM element is a common scenario based on various business requirements. Since
the time of SPA (single page application) is evolved, you will find that on scroll position of browser, new
elements are shown and previous elements are hidden. There are tons of jQuery plugins available which can
show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll position but itâ€™s not advisable to use jQuery plugins for
things which you can do with simple jQuery code. So in this post, letâ€™s see how to show/hide any HTML element
based on the scroll position in the browser window using jQuery.Showing/hiding any HTML DOM element is a common
scenario based on various business requirements. Since the time of SPA (single page application) is evolved,
you will find that on scroll position of browser, new elements are shown and previous elements are hidden.
There are tons of jQuery plugins available which can show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll position
but itâ€™s not advisable to use jQuery plugins for things which you can do with simple jQuery code. So in this
post, letâ€™s see how to show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll position in the browser window using
jQuery.Showing/hiding any HTML DOM element is a common scenario based on various business requirements. Since
the time of SPA (single page application) is evolved, you will find that on scroll position of browser, new
elements are shown and previous elements are hidden. There are tons of jQuery plugins available which can
show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll position but itâ€™s not advisable to use jQuery plugins for
things which you can do with simple jQuery code. So in this post, letâ€™s see how to show/hide any HTML element
based on the scroll position in the browser window using jQuery.Showing/hiding any HTML DOM element is a common
scenario based on various business requirements. Since the time of SPA (single page application) is evolved,
you will find that on scroll position of browser, new elements are shown and previous elements are hidden.
There are tons of jQuery plugins available which can show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll position
but itâ€™s not advisable to use jQuery plugins for things which you can do with simple jQuery code. So in this
post, letâ€™s see how to show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll position in the browser window using
jQuery.
Showing/hiding any HTML DOM element is a common scenario based on various business requirements. Since the time
of SPA (single page application) is evolved, you will find that on scroll position of browser, new elements are
shown and previous elements are hidden. There are tons of jQuery plugins available which can show/hide any HTML
element based on the scroll position but itâ€™s not advisable to use jQuery plugins for things which you can do
with simple jQuery code. So in this post, letâ€™s see how to show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll
position in the browser window using jQuery.
Showing/hiding any HTML DOM element is a common scenario based on various business requirements. Since the time
of SPA (single page application) is evolved, you will find that on scroll position of browser, new elements are
shown and previous elements are hidden. There are tons of jQuery plugins available which can show/hide any HTML
element based on the scroll position but itâ€™s not advisable to use jQuery plugins for things which you can do
with simple jQuery code. So in this post, letâ€™s see how to show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll
position in the browser window using jQuery.
Showing/hiding any HTML DOM element is a common scenario based on various business requirements. Since the time
of SPA (single page application) is evolved, you will find that on scroll position of browser, new elements are
shown and previous elements are hidden. There are tons of jQuery plugins available which can show/hide any HTML
element based on the scroll position but itâ€™s not advisable to use jQuery plugins for things which you can do
with simple jQuery code. So in this post, letâ€™s see how to show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll
position in the browser window using jQuery.
Showing/hiding any HTML DOM element is a common scenario based on various business requirements. Since the time
of SPA (single page application) is evolved, you will find that on scroll position of browser, new elements are
shown and previous elements are hidden. There are tons of jQuery plugins available which can show/hide any HTML
element based on the scroll position but itâ€™s not advisable to use jQuery plugins for things which you can do
with simple jQuery code. So in this post, letâ€™s see how to show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll
position in the browser window using jQuery.
Showing/hiding any HTML DOM element is a common scenario based on various business requirements. Since the time
of SPA (single page application) is evolved, you will find that on scroll position of browser, new elements are
shown and previous elements are hidden. There are tons of jQuery plugins available which can show/hide any HTML
element based on the scroll position but itâ€™s not advisable to use jQuery plugins for things which you can do
with simple jQuery code. So in this post, letâ€™s see how to show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll
position in the browser window using jQuery.
Showing/hiding any HTML DOM element is a common scenario based on various business requirements. Since the time
of SPA (single page application) is evolved, you will find that on scroll position of browser, new elements are
shown and previous elements are hidden. There are tons of jQuery plugins available which can show/hide any HTML
element based on the scroll position but itâ€™s not advisable to use jQuery plugins for things which you can do
with simple jQuery code. So in this post, letâ€™s see how to show/hide any HTML element based on the scroll
position in the browser window using jQuery.

.nb-header {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: auto;
left: 0;
width: 100% !important;
background:#fff200;
padding: 12px 0;
z-index: 1000;
@media(max-width: 767px) {
padding: 15px 0;
}
.nb-logo {
width: 45px;
float: left;
}
.nb-logo a {
display: block;
}
.nb-logo img {
display: block;
}
}

.nb-hamburger {
float: right;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0.6s;
}

.nav-up {
top: -75px;
}

.nb-menu-bar {
text-align: center;
display: none;
background: #fff200;
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
// right:0;
// top: 0;
// left: 0;
// width: 100%;

ul {
padding: 50px 0;
margin-top: 70px;
@media(min-width: 767px) {
padding: 200px 0;
}
}


li {
display: block;
margin: 25px 20px 0 20px;
@media(min-width: 767px) {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

@media(min-width:800px) {
margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

@media(min-width:1100px) {
margin: 0 30px 0 30px;
}

}

a {
display: block;
font-size: 25px;    
color: #1b1b1c;
font-weight: 700;

@media(min-width:800px) {
font-size: 28px;
}

@media(min-width:1100px) {
font-size: 36px;
}

span.nb-menu-sub {
font-size: 15px;
color: #4a4a4a;
display: block;
font-weight: $primary-weight;
margin-top: 5px;
@media(min-width: 991px) {
font-size: 18px;
margin-top: 15px;
}
}

}

span.nb-menu-link {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
&::before {
content: '';
height: 5px;
width: 0;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 2px;
background: #fff200;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 5px;
z-index: -1;
transition: all 0.5s;
}
}

a:hover span.nb-menu-link:before {
width: 100%;
}




}




.hamburger-content {
display: none;
background: #0000;
}

.hamburger-container {
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px 0 15px 15px;
margin-left: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger-grid {
width: 20px;
transition: all 0.5s;
}

.hamburger-line {
height: 2px;
width: 20px;
display: block;
background: #000;
margin-top: 5px;
}


var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
if (didScroll) {
hasScrolled();
didScroll = false;
}
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

// Make sure they scroll more than delta
if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
return;

// If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
// This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
// Scroll Down
$('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
} else {
// Scroll Up
if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
$('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
}
}

lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Hey guys, I'm trying to do header animation. When we scroll down the header will hide. When we scroll top the header will show. But the problem is there is a hamburger menu. When we open the menu by clicking that menu the animation of header don't want to happen. when we close the menu then the header should work with animation. Can we do that using my code? I have attached my entire code above. Please go through it. And please help if you guys know about that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is...Now check

```js
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
if (didScroll) {
hasScrolled();
didScroll = false;
}
}, 250);
$('.nb-hamburger').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('is-open');
});
function hasScrolled() {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

// Make sure they scroll more than delta
if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
return;

// If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
// This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight && !$('.nb-hamburger.is-open').length){
// Scroll Down
$('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
} else {
// Scroll Up
if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height() && !$('.nb-hamburger.is-open').length) {
$('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
}
}

lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
body {
  height:2000px;
}
.nb-header {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: auto;
left: 0;
width: 100% !important;
background:#fff200;
padding: 12px 0;
z-index: 1000;
@media(max-width: 767px) {
padding: 15px 0;
}
.nb-logo {
width: 45px;
float: left;
}
.nb-logo a {
display: block;
}
.nb-logo img {
display: block;
}
}

.nb-hamburger {
float: right;
cursor: pointer;
transition: 0.6s all;
height:0;
}

.nav-up {
top: -75px;
transition: 0.2s all;
}
.nav-down {
transition: 0.2s all;
}
.nb-menu-bar {
text-align: center;
display: none;
background: #fff200;
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
// right:0;
// top: 0;
// left: 0;
// width: 100%;

ul {
padding: 50px 0;
margin-top: 70px;
@media(min-width: 767px) {
padding: 200px 0;
}
}


li {
display: block;
margin: 25px 20px 0 20px;
@media(min-width: 767px) {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

@media(min-width:800px) {
margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

@media(min-width:1100px) {
margin: 0 30px 0 30px;
}

}

a {
display: block;
font-size: 25px;    
color: #1b1b1c;
font-weight: 700;

@media(min-width:800px) {
font-size: 28px;
}

@media(min-width:1100px) {
font-size: 36px;
}

span.nb-menu-sub {
font-size: 15px;
color: #4a4a4a;
display: block;
font-weight: $primary-weight;
margin-top: 5px;
@media(min-width: 991px) {
font-size: 18px;
margin-top: 15px;
}
}

}

span.nb-menu-link {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
&::before {
content: '';
height: 5px;
width: 0;
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 2px;
background: #fff200;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 5px;
z-index: -1;
transition: all 0.5s;
}
}

a:hover span.nb-menu-link:before {
width: 100%;
}




}




.hamburger-content {
display: none;
background: #0000;
}

.hamburger-container {
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px 0 15px 15px;
margin-left: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger-grid {
width: 20px;
transition: all 0.5s;
}

.hamburger-line {
height: 2px;
width: 20px;
display: block;
background: #000;
margin-top: 5px;
}

.nb-hamburger.is-open {
  height:250px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.nb-logo.row-fluid {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<header class="nb-header row-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="nb-logo row-fluid">
          <a href="#">
          logo
          </a>
       </div>
       <div class="nb-hamburger">
          Hamburger
       </div>
    </div>
   </header>
   <!--nb-header-->
   <div class="nb-menu-bar row-fluid">
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <ul>
  <li> <a href="#"> <span class="nb-menu-link"> Work </span> <span class="nb-menu-sub">
     What we’ve done </span> </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#"> <span class="nb-menu-link"> Services </span> <span class="nb-menu-sub">
     What we do </span> </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#"> <span class="nb-menu-link"> Studio </span> <span class="nb-menu-sub">
     Who we are </span> </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#"> <span class="nb-menu-link"> Contact </span> <span class="nb-menu-sub">
     Get in touch </span> </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#"> <span class="nb-menu-link"> Careers </span> <span class="nb-menu-sub">
     Join the team </span> </a> 
  </li>
      </ul>
                </div>
             </div>
             </body>
```

Comment: Add if condition for adding class .nav-down if hamburger menu is not open

Comment: Hey CodeGator, can you give me an example to do that? I don't know much about javascript.

Comment: Can you tell me, What will be the class when hamburger menu is open?

Comment: Hey  CodeGator, you can use whatever you want. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you help me?